# jLabels automatically goes newline

Tags: java, swing, newline, jlabel

I have some jlabels which works fine, but i need them to be "bold".So i used html to introduce strong tags. Now my text is bold but it goes newline when the end of the jlabel is reached instead of truncate it adding some end dots, like was before using html. Minimum, Maximum and Preferred size of jlabels are set to [80,14] and they are not resizeable.Here some code:

```
 public PanelArchivio(Lavoro lavoro) {
    //Nimbus ha un bug che riguarda il colore di sfondo dei textpanel e altri pannelli di testo
    //Creo il colore e lo metto di default al background dei textpane
    Color bgColor = new Color(255, 255, 153);
    UIDefaults defaults = new UIDefaults();
    defaults.put("TextPane[Enabled].backgroundPainter", bgColor);
    initComponents();
    this.lavoro = lavoro;
    jLabel_Cod.setText("<html><strong>"+this.lavoro.getCodice()+"</strong></html>");
    jLabel_DataCons.setText("<html><strong>"+Integer.toString(this.lavoro.getDataCons().getDate())+"/"+Integer.toString(this.lavoro.getDataCons().getMonth())+"/"+Integer.toString(this.lavoro.getDataCons().getYear())+"</strong></html>");

    if(this.lavoro.getOp1().equals(""))
        jLabel_Op1.setText("");
    else
        jLabel_Op1.setText("<html><strong>"+this.lavoro.getOp1()+"</strong></html>");
    if(this.lavoro.getOp2().equals(""))
        jLabel_Op2.setText("");
    else
        jLabel_Op2.setText(this.lavoro.getOp3());
    if(this.lavoro.getOp3().equals(""))
        jLabel_Op3.setText("");
    else
        jLabel_Op3.setText("<html><strong>"+this.lavoro.getOp3()+"</strong></html>");

    jTextArea_Note.setText(this.lavoro.getNote());
    jTextArea_Note.setLineWrap(true);
    jTextArea_Note.setCaretPosition(0);

    String ThumbnailPath = "C:/DecoLedisApp/Media/Disegni/Thumbnails/"+this.lavoro.getCodice()+".png";
    //Se il percorso è corretto setto il Thumbnail, altrimenti setto un immagine di default
    try {
        File f = new File(ThumbnailPath);
        if (f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {
            //Faccio un flush dell'immagine caricata, evitando che java
            //utilizzi l'immagine in cache senza ricaricare il file
            ImageIcon FlushedIcon = new ImageIcon(ThumbnailPath);
            FlushedIcon.getImage().flush();
            jLabel_Thumbnail.setIcon(FlushedIcon);
        } else {
            jLabel_Thumbnail.setIcon(new ImageIcon(PanelModOperatore.class.getResource("/Images/EmptyThumbnail.png")));
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        jLabel_Thumbnail.setIcon(new ImageIcon(PanelModOperatore.class.getResource("/Images/EmptyThumbnail.png")));
    }

}
```

As you can see, lines 2 and 3 have the same text set but the bolded one goes newline.
How to avoid this?

[image]

Comment: Why isn't the GUI using layouts?  1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: *"Here some code:"*  Note that an MCVE/SSCCE is not 'some code' but a very specific form of code.  Please follow the links and read about it.

Comment: More info added. Should be clear now

Comment: An uncompilable code snippet.  Since you apparently failed to read the links I provided, I've decided this is 'poorly researched' and earns a down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of messing around with HTML, why not just use a bold font?

```
   Font f = myLabel.getFont();
   myLabel.setFont( new Font( f.getName(), Font.BOLD, f.getSize() ) );
```

Comment: Thanks fred, i'll do that. Already thought about this solution but i was wandering why html works like this :)